# Exporting a list as RawData or Data

Tags: list-manipulation, export, data

My problem is quite simple yet I do not seem to figure out the solution to it. I am simply trying to export a list in *Mathematica*, actually a list of lists of lists etc, something like `{{...,{...}},{...}}`, but the `Head` is a list. I want to export this as raw  *Mathematica* symbols so that I can access it later.

Lets take a simple list, say

```
list = {1,a,Pi};
```

I am trying:

```
Export["listname",list,"RawData"]
```

and also

```
Export["listname",list,"Data"]
```

but getting the following error:

> ```
> Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file listname. >>
> ```

This works for other formats such as `CSV` or `TXT`.

Comment: Have you seen `DumpSave[]`?

Comment: @belisarius was not aware of DumpSave[] and Save[] which seem to work for my purpose. Still don't understand why Export[] does not work but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Öskå saving as "Text" does not work well in my case because I am actually trying to save lists with many different levels. It would be ideal to just save in Mathematica format.

Comment: "data"  is an *element* not a *format*. The error is because you havent specified a format and none can be inferred from the file name

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for clearing that but could you be more explicit? How could I save my list without converting it to another data format? I guess the command would be Export["Listname.(some extension)", list, "Data"]

Comment: see simon's answer.. note wdx is a  binary format, so useful mostly if you only need to read it back with mathematica.  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html

Comment: So it turns out that i could simply use Save["filename",symbol] and then read it back with symbolname = Get["filename"]. Symbol in my case is the list, which is actually a multi-dimensional list. I suppose this is equivalent to using DumpSave[]. Thanks for all the insight and the fast responses!

Answer (score 5):

Two options for exporting arbitrary *Mathematica* expressions are to use [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Put.html) or to `Export` to [WDX](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/WDX.html) format.

```
list = {1, a, π};

Put[list, "test.anything"];    
Get["test.anything"]

(* {1, a, π} *)

Export["test.wdx", list];   
Import["test.wdx"]

(* {1, a, π} *)
```

Comment: I've seen people suggest exporting using `Compress` as well - I don't have the experience to say if this is worth mentioning or not

Comment: Thanks!! It also works with Save["test",list] and Get["test"]